# MySQL syntax: bigger than value, but NOT IN (...)

Tags: mysql, sql

Tables:

**bookings**: id, user_id, object_id, date1, ...

**booking_status**: id, book_id, status

status is int, range from 1 to 9 (request, confirmed, paid, cancelled by user and that sort of stuff), so I need all bookings, where status is at least 4 (which means paid) but no value bigger than 4 (which would mean cancelled etc).

Till now the SELECT looks about like this (I left out some fields (...) to shorten it):

```
SELECT b.date1, ..., u.name FROM bookings b
    LEFT JOIN user u ON (b.user_id = u.id)
    LEFT JOIN booking_status bs ON (b.id=bs.book_id)
  WHERE ((b.object_id=$object_id) AND (bs.status NOT IN (5,6,7,8,9)));"
```

...but it still selects those bookings that have booking status bigger than 4 as well. Any ideas how I need to change the query??

Thank you very much in advance!

---

UPDATE: thank you all again, I am amazed with how many great ideas you have come up with! There is really many ways to do it and I learned a lot from you, so thank you again! I will try all your suggestions and see for the performance, for now I mixed your solutions to this query, <strike>which works for now but I need to test it further:</strike>

```
SELECT b.date, ..., u.name FROM bookings b
LEFT JOIN user u ON (b.user_id = u.id)
LEFT JOIN booking_status bs ON (b.id=bs.book_id AND bs.status<=4)
WHERE (b.object_id=$object_id) HAVING MAX(bs.status)=4
```

it does not return multiple rows, but returns the rows with 4, excludes the rows with more than 4 and has no subqueries...

EDIT 2: <strike>I edited the query again... with HAVING MAX(bs.status)=4 it then works...</strike>

EDIT 3: sorry, after testing different cases I have to admit I was much too fast by saying it works...

Comment: What about `AND status <= 4`?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a row that is erroneously returned by that query?

Comment: it must be at least 4, but not bigger than 4... e.g. in booking status there is id=1, book_id=1, status=1; then id=1, book_id=1, status=4; and id=1, book_id=1, status=5;... it should not return booking number 1, as in booking_status there is a row where status contains 5...

Comment: @JamWaffles: yes, that is a good idea, however it would still select those bookings that have a row with status 4 but also status 5... so i want to exclude those bookings where there is a row for them with status bigger than 4...

Comment: did you make sure there is no such thing as `current_status` in bookings table?

Comment: @deathApril: what do you mean with "current_status"? actually, this could be another idea as well, as there is a field timestamp in booking_status, so probably you could use ORDER BY timestamp and LIMIT=1 as well...? EDIT: no, you could not use LIMIT, as there are more rows... stupid thought, sorry...

Comment: @Chris But it wouldn't; `<= 4` means, in this context, "select all rows with a status **less than or equal to** 4". This means _not 5 and upwards.

Comment: @JamWaffles: well, I tried it, it was my first thought too! The reason is, it selects those rows, because they actually have a value 4 or lower... but mysql does not seem to care if there is a value higher than that, too... in other words: if there was only a value like 5, it would not be selected, as it is not 4 or lower... but I need it to be upside down!

Comment: by `current_status` i mean whether you are sure you can't select the current status directly from table `bookings` instead of from table `booking_status` - because the second table stores all the statuses and it would make more sense for the application to store the current status in a separate field, not computing it from such a big table

Comment: please don't use `having` without a `group by` - there is 99% chance that it behaves differently from what you think it does (and the results are good only if all the books for the particular object_id have the good status or not a single one has it)

Comment: @deathApril: alright, but why and how to use it?

Comment: copy the columns from the **select** section - i.e. `GROUP BY b.date, ..., u.name` (but without the aliases `as "book_date"` if you use them in the select) - e.g. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inspired by ruakh's solution without the correlated subqueries:

```
select ...
from bookings b
join (select book_id from booking_status group by book_id having max(status) = 4
     ) bs on b.id = bs.book_id
left join user u on b.user_id = u.id
```

Comment: that is a good idea with the having max(status)=4, I tried with max, but did not come up to use it with having like this! that is great and you don't even need the subselect, it works like this: SELECT b.date1, ..., u.name FROM bookings b
    LEFT JOIN user u ON (b.user_id = u.id)
    LEFT JOIN booking_status bs ON (b.id=bs.book_id)
  WHERE (b.object_id=$object_id) HAVING MAX(bs.status)=4;" however, I would need the "at least 4" as well, which cannot be done with MIN()...

Comment: for "at least 4" and "not greater than 4", the only option is `=4` - or am i missing something??

Comment: well, the trick is, that in the table booking_status, there are entries for the booking where in one row the status is 4 but if it is cancelled later, there is an entry with status 5... if it is not yet paid, the status is below 4, so only <=4 would select those rows too. of course you are right, if there was only one entry, it would simply be 4! ;)

Comment: i can't see a `group by` in your comment - if `having` works at all, it would compute the `max` for the whole result, i.e. it would return all rows or none at all - not sure if that is the desired output (BTW, in the `group by` you need to put all your non-aggregate columns)

Comment: 3 rows `1,2,3` => `max() = 3`, 5 rows `1,2,3,4,5` => `max() = 5`, so the contition `max() = 4` is sufficient to filter out both of the unwanted cases (in my query)

Comment: no it was not enough, as obviously max()=3 was still selected... I needed to place in LEFT JOIN ON(bs.status=4)...

Comment: the select in my answer could not possibly select values with max() = 3 - my `join` is an inner join by design, `left join` would completelly miss the point...

Comment: just tried the queries on tables with about a million rows... query with MAX() took more than 2 sec whereas the same with only status=4 took 0.0013sec... tested in MyISAM and InnoDB, about the same results...

Comment: which one is "the same"? one of the other answers? accept that one answer so we know which one is the best ;)) or my query without max()? in that case you can't compare performance with a query that won't give you correct results.

Comment: no, what I wanted to point out was that MAX() seems to be very slow. sure, the thing is I am still trying what query gives the right results... I'll let you know asap...

Comment: it's not possible to get aggregate information from more than 1 row without an aggregate function or its join equivalent (answer by Marcus Adams) or a subquery... and 2 seconds for milions of rows where you do not have the information easily accessible is not that bad

Comment: yes, you are right deathApril! :) your query really stunned me, honestly! 2sec was not meant as a criticism ;) thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding correctly, what you need is this:

```
SELECT b.date1, ..., u.name
  FROM bookings b
  LEFT JOIN user u ON b.user_id = u.id
 WHERE b.object_id = ...
   AND EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM booking_status bs
           WHERE bs.book_id = b.id
             AND bs.status = 4
        )
   AND NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM booking_status bs
           WHERE bs.book_id = b.id
             AND bs.status > 4
        )
;
```

The problem with your current query is that it filters out all joined rows where `bs.status > 4`, but it doesn't filter out joined rows that have the same `bookings.id` as a joined row where `bs.status > 4`.

Comment: thank you very much, ruakh! So, a sub select is necessary? your query looks great... just wondering, if it was fast enough for a few million rows?

Comment: @Chris: You're welcome! Regarding performance: you'll have to try it and see. If it improves performance, the `AND EXISTS ( ... bs.status = 4)` can easily be converted into an `INNER JOIN`. The `AND NOT EXISTS ( ... bs.status > 4)` would be trickier, but if necessary, it could be converted into a `LEFT JOIN booking_status2 bs2 ON bs2.status > 4` with a `WHERE bs2.status IS NULL` . . . though it would take some effort to get that right. IIRC, the way that MySQL handles such joins, you'd have to wrap your whole query in a subquery.

Comment: ruakh, I am just testing your query now with tables that have between 800,000 and 1.5 million rows, unfortunately it is slow like hell, meaning it has already been loading for several minutes for one query and still has not finished yet... :S

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method without subqueries:

```
SELECT b.date1, ..., u.name
FROM bookings b
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = b.user_id
JOIN booking_status bs1
  ON bs1.book_id = b.id AND bs1.status = 4
LEFT JOIN booking_status bs2
  ON bs2.book_id = b.id AND bs2.status > 4
WHERE b.object_id = $object_id
  AND b2.book_id IS NULL
```

This query eliminates any row where there is a status for the same id that is greater than 4.

Comment: wow, that looks great, too... what is the difference between JOIN and LEFT JOIN here?

Comment: The `JOIN` is required here because I have specified the criteria to filter with in the ON clause rather than the WHERE clause. The idea was to hint to MySQL what rows to eliminate sooner rather than later, and I felt it made the query more readable.

Comment: thank you Marcus! However, I just tried it and it does not exclude the rows but returns them even multiple times now... did I do anything wrong? And is b2.book_id in the last line actually bs2.book_id?

Comment: @Chris, if you are getting duplicates or the rows aren't being excluded, then ensure that you have `AND b2.book_id IS NULL` in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Marcus, thank you... but I have the query exactly like you do, with IS NULL... it selects the right rows, but returns them as often as many status entries there are in booking_status... the only thing I have, is bs2.book_id instead of b2.book_id...

Comment: @Chris: You need to change Marcus's `AND bs1.status <= 4` to `AND bs1.status = 4`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
SELECT id, 
       user_id, 
       object_id, 
       date1 
FROM   bookings b 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT book_id 
                   FROM   booking_status 
                   GROUP  BY book_id 
                   HAVING MAX(CASE 
                                WHEN status >= 4 THEN status 
                              END) = 4) bs 
         ON bs.book_id = b.id
```

(or version without subselect in response to comments)

```
SELECT b.id, 
       b.user_id, 
       b.object_id, 
       b.date1 
FROM   bookings b 
       INNER JOIN booking_status bs 
         ON bs.book_id = b.id 
GROUP  BY b.id /* Other RDBMSs would require all columns listed*/
HAVING MAX(CASE 
             WHEN bs.status >= 4 THEN bs.status 
           END) = 4
```

Comment: omg, you guys are all great, really!! seems like there are 1000 ways to do it... still having a sub select, but thank you anyway! :)

Comment: @Chris - It doesn't have to have a subselect. You could just use a normal `JOIN ... GROUP BY`. No idea if one is better performing than the other in MySQL I just did it that way as in RDBMSs other than MySQL you then need to list all selected columns from `bookings` in the `GROUP BY` list.